# Xcode - Looking at logs in debug mode? (iOS)

Tags: ios, debug-symbols

Let's say you run your application from your Xcode. When it's running from your Xcode, you can see the logs in the debugger. Once you stop the application and run the app again from your device by tapping it, you won't be able to see the logs in the debugger although the application is running in debug mode.

Is there any way to enable logging in the debugger though you are not running the app from Xcode (but the app is compiled in debug mode)?

If not, how do debug symbols (debug mode will add debug symbols to the binaries) help us to debug our application? I can only see the benefit when I symbolicate crash logs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Xcode Organizer window. Select the Devices tab. Then choose the connected device and select Console under the device. You will see more than just your app's logs messages but they will be there.

Answer (score 0):

There's a useful utility called [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1465)

Comment: This is a broken link